# What is the Dialog Box used by the Ubuntu Server Installer?

Tags: server, dialog

A dialog box displays user-friendly boxes from shell scripts. I'm looking for the dialog box used in the Ubuntu Server 13.04 installer. I know a couple of alternatives but they don't fit what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess it's part of the Debian installer.  If I were you, I'd check it out (via Subversion, ugh) according to http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/CheckOut, then poke around and see if you stumble onto it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the exact package used in the Ubuntu Installer. It's called [Whiptail](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/whiptail)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean what's drawing the boxes? That should be [Dialog](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/dialog)